# Select subset of elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

A part of an HTML page consisting of links is given below:

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="myPersonalProject.html">myPersonalProject (a local html file)</a></li>
    <li><a href="cv.pdf">my CV (a local PDF file)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive/2014.zip">archive (a local ZIP file)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf">ECMAScript Language Specification (an external PDF)</a></li>
    <li><a href="../pdfs/christmas/">Christmas cards (a local directory with pdf in the pathname - but NOT a pdf file)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://noppa.tkk.fi/">Noppa (an external link)</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I need to select the links whose targets end with anything (.*), and which do NOT end with (.pdf) and similarly do NOT end with (.html), and apply a CSS class to it. I need to use jQuery for this. I tried to do it with filter, but made a mess of it, as I have just started learning jQuery:

```
    $("a[href$='.*']").filter(function(){
           $("a[href$!='.pdf']").filter(function(){
                  $("a[href$!='.html']").addClass("download");
            });
     });
```

I know it's completely wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it. I googled around, but the function() inside filter() is not really clear. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a regex with some simple tests to filter the anchors

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    var m = this.href.match(/\.(.{3,4})$/), e = m ? m.shift() : null;
    return e && e.indexOf('/') == -1 && e.match(/(pdf|html)/) == null;
}).addClass('download');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/s1mwLoe0/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery attribute selectors don't allow wildcards or regexp. But you don't need to use filter to remove the `.pdf`, you can use a `:not` selector:

```
$("a:not([href$=.pdf]):not([href$=.html])").addClass("download");
```

And when you use `.filter()`, the function is just supposed to return a boolean (indicating whether that element should be included or not in the result), it shouldn't operate on the elements themselves -- you do that on the value returned by `.filter`, e.g.

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
    return ...;
}).addClass("download");
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#expr) as,

```
$('a')
    .filter(function() {
        //use your required regex to check for link
        return this.href.match(/[^.]*?\.(?!pdf|html)/gi);
    })
    .addClass("download"); //if matched, "download" class is added
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href]").filter(function (i) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    return (href.indexOf(".pdf") == -1 && href.indexOf(".html") == -1);
})
.addClass("download");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, it worked! And thanks to everyone else too for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

While you say you "*need to do this with jQuery*," I wanted to offer a plain JavaScript alternative (for yourself or others, in future):

```
// calls Array.prototype.forEach(), using the array-like NodeList
// returned by document.querySelectorAll(), iterating over that NodeList
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li a'), function (aElem) {
    // 'aElem' is the current array-element (the <a>)

    // if the aElem.href property does not (note the '!') end with
    // either 'pdf' or 'html' (RegExp.prototype.test() returns
    // a Boolean)
    if (!(/(pdf|html)$/).test(aElem.href)) {
        // we add the 'download' class to the element:
        aElem.classList.add('download');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uwvqv1bn/).

Alternatively:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li a'), function (aElem) {
    // if the final part of the href (following the final '.' character)
    // is not found in the array (and thus an index of -1):
    if (['pdf','html'].indexOf(aElem.href.split('.').pop()) === -1) {
        aElem.classList.add('download');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uwvqv1bn/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [JavaScript regular expression guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
$("a").each(function( index ) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(!((href.toLowerCase().indexOf(".pdf") >= 0) || (href.toLowerCase().indexOf(".html") >= 0))){
        $(this).addClass("download");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm late to the party, minor changes to DemoUser's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26834940/381709)

which takes care of # anchor in the URL

```
$('a')
    .filter(function() {
        // take care of anchor # in download URL
        return !this.href.match(/\.(pdf|html)(#.*)?$/gi);
    })
    .addClass("download"); //if matched, "download" class is added
```